# Corda - Version Upgrade & Gradle Tooling Issues

Tags: gradle, corda

I've just upgraded a Corda project from 4.1 to 4.3 however there are unresolved dependencies, specifically

```
org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:5.4.1
```

Which is required by

```
net.corda:corda-node-driver:4.3
```

The following repositories are enabled in my `build.gradle` configuration

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda' }
}
```

This seems to happen almost every time I perform a Corda version upgrade, and I've yet to fully understand why...

Answer (score 3):

Took a little digging but this was missing from my repositories configuration...

```
 maven { url 'https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases' }
```